# Visual Studio Community Centralizing 3rd party dlls for reference

Tags: visual-studio, dll, code-organization

Hello I'm trying to learn how to build my own library (using SDL2) that I can use for other projects in the same solution. I know how to set up a project that others can reference for libraries and includes but I'm having an issue when it comes to the .dll files.

I want a centralized location that all projects can use instead of just copying the DLLs to the project folder for every project. I don't want to recopy all SDL2 dll files for every project when SDL2 updates.

I know I can use Nuget to solve my problem but I want to learn how to do it manually.

Comment: You **need** to copy the dlls to each project output folder, ultimately because the code runs from there, but also it provides the reference API for compilation. What Nuget and all package managers end up doing is just to copy files in that way.

Comment: @Alejandro, how could it be that I need to, how does visual studio know where to look for the dlls? There must be some path that specifies where they are. Why can't it just be changed to somewhere else?

Comment: @Thedv8ed1  Windows includes certain system libraries, which are versioned and stacked and managed by microsoft.  But doesn't really apply to hired parties. Windows reccently introduced a package manage, which may help this problem if you can convice upstream to deal with the microsoft process. Dependency management is on the of the big issue of software development and systems management.